# What are alternate words for the exclamation 'hooray!'

Tags: synonyms

"Hurrah!" seems like a different form of hooray.

"Yippee!" is the only other one I can find.

Comment: Don't you mean *hurrah*?

Comment: google for 'interjection'

Comment: I googled for 'positive interjections' and found this. http://www.positivethesaurus.com/p/positive-interjections.html

As this question was closed this comment will have to do. :)

Answer (score 2):

***[Huzzah](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=huzzah)***

***[Woot](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=woot)***

***[Booyah](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=booyah)***

Among many more - click the links ...